# What happens if I upvote an ad?

Tags: support, advertising

I've been on stackoverflow for a short time, however, I have seen many ads of this site. I liked them, so I clicked the "like" button. But... What happens if I click it? Does that info count on some sort of survey?

Comment: I guess you'll get similar content in future ads.

Comment: [*Once you have 200 rep...*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads)

Comment: That doesn't give me info: I'm just saying that what happens when I click the "I like this ad" on the ad.

Comment: [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yw0c7aE_8NU)

Comment: thanks to a well populated `hosts` file I don't get to see any ads '-)

Comment: We use this info directionally to inform clients on ad performance. If we see a lot of downvotes in comparison to upvotes, we may suggest that a client change an ad or remove it. Alternatively, if they are running multiple ads in rotation and one is performing better/getting more upvotes, we may suggest an increase in the percentage that ad is served.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Those ads are served via [Adzerk](http://www.adzerk.com), and the thumbs up/down buttons are part of their [ad feedback](http://help.adzerk.com/hc/en-us/articles/206421046-Ad-Feedback) feature.

TL;DR: The feedback is used by our internal ads team to evaluate the running ad campaigns. While I believe there's no functional change that occurs from up-voting an ad, down-voting an ad presents you with a short survey asking why you down-voted it, and then you will never see that ad again.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I like how TL;DR section is longer than the post content

Comment: @kukis he's tl;dr'ing (new verb?) the article.

Comment: @rossipedia is 100% right, but I wanted to chime in and say yes, upvoting does nothing but put positive vibes into an industry rife with negative vibes. While it's not currently part of any plans, maybe in the future we'll explore using that data to further improve advertising on SO.

Comment: *"and then you will never see that ad again"* - what if I downvote every single currently displayed ad?

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure you won't see any ads (not 100% on that, but it seems logical).

Comment: You will most certainly see the ad again if you clear cookies or switch devices, unless Adzerk is tied into SE membership.

Comment: *what if I downvote every single currently displayed ad* There are always more ads :-)

Comment: @Braiam The word is "summarizing."

Comment: @Eric J. All glory to AdBlock Plus

Comment: My adblocker is actually disabled on stackoverflow.

Comment: `.stackexchange.com` and `.stackoverflow.com` are a few exceptions on my adblocker.  The ads here are really relevant to the audience and I have often discovered new tools from the ads; and as they offer [free ads to open-source projects](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/) its one way for me to keep support those projects.

Comment: Just to clarify - "and then you will never see that ad again" - advertisers sometimes have the same ad in different targeted placements. You will not see the ad from the placement where you downvoted it, but you may see it as part of a differently targeted placement.